# Get the value of a ctypes.c_ulong pointer

Tags: python, ctypes

For example:

```
pointer = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_ulong)
b = pointer(ctypes.c_ulong(20))
```

How do I get the int value of `b`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You mean, dereference `b` to get that `c_ulong(20)`?  That's `b.contents`.

Or do you mean, see where in memory that pointer happens to point, as if it was an integer rather than a pointer?  That's `ctypes.cast(b, ctypes.c_void_p).value`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! `b.contents` it is!!

Comment: Or just use `b[0]`, which calls the type's `getfunc` to return a Python integer, e.g. `b[0] == 20`. Also, you can only cast to a pointer type, so the 2nd suggestion will fail. The quickest way to get just the address from some other pointer is to use the buffer protocol: `ctypes.c_void_p.from_buffer(b).value`. Or use `ctypes.cast(b, ctypes.c_void_p).value`, but `cast` isn't as efficient since it's implemented using a foreign function call.

Comment: Just a note that you can only cast to a pointer type: `types.cast(b, ctypes.c_ulong)` is illegal. However, you can instead say `types.cast(b, ctypes.c_void_p).value)`.